# Use cases for Math.clz32 in practice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what use cases could I find in practice where I'd need to apply `Math.clz32` Javascript function.

Thanks

Comment: This sort of thing is better answered [by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Applications) and similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting leading zeros in an integer number is a critical operation in many DSP algorithms, such as normalization of samples in sound or video processing, as well as in real-time schedulers to quickly find the highest-priority task ready-to-run.

Answer (score 2):

## [clz32()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32)

> The `Math.clz32()` function returns the number of leading zero bits in the 32-bit binary representation of a number.

It could be used to convert 64bit integer/float to 32bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've used CLZ(32) in microcontroller code many times, mostly for DSP and fixed-point math.

While possible, I don't see myself doing much of that in JavaScript.

But I did have use for it just now; to verify a network mask provided as an array of four numbers.

```
function is_valid_netmask(ip) {
    let ip32 = ((ip[0] << 24) | (ip[1] << 16) | (ip[2] << 8) | ip[3]) ^ -1;
    return ip32 == (1 << (32 - Math.clz32(ip32)) >>> 0) - 1;
}
```